# HTML Alert enqueueMessage

Tags: joomla-3.x

Joomla 3.10.1

I am using the following code to display a custom message in one of my components:

```
$app->enqueueMessage(JText::sprintf('This is my message'), 'warning');
```

This produces a **dismissible** alert on the front end like below:

```
<div id="system-message-container">
    <div id="system-message">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <a aria-label="" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
            <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning</h4>
            <div>
                <div>This is my message</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make this alert non-dismissible without using css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in Joomla 3, because the `close` button is hardcode in the layout.

One option you have is to override the layout, like so:

1. Create the following directory tree for your component: `components/com_xxxx/layouts/joomla/system`
2. Copy `layouts/joomla/system/message.php` to the directory you created in the last step.
3. Open the copied `message.php` and remove the close button (should be line 21)